# Tamaño de memoria agotado, PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estoy realizando una consulta a Mysql, en la que obtengo aproximadamente 55k registros, posterior a esto se exporta en un archivo excel.

```
SELECT CONCAT(cl,'-', id, '/', year) folio, nombre,evento,estado,impacto,equipo,proveedor,replace(comentarios,'\\n',' ') comentarios,lugar,area,fecha_falla,fecha_soporte,fecha_fin_falla,ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, fecha_soporte, fecha_fin_falla) / 60,2) tiempo,
reporte_refaccion,cantidad_refaccion,codigos_refaccion,cod_ref_proveedor,sit,fecha_escalado,reporte_escalado,fecha_fin_escalado,emp
FROM bi_view;
```

Inicialmente estaba recuperando los datos con la siguiente instrucción:
`$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);`
pero al aumentar la cantidad de registros esto se volvió un problema, por el tema de la memoria excedida.

Lo que hice fue cambiar la forma en la que almaceno la información de la consulta:

```
$reportes = array();
while ($fila = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $reportes[] = $fila;
}
```

Sin embargo se sigue mostrando en error: `Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)` no quisiera modificar el archivo de configuración para permitir más uso de memoria porque entiendo que sería solo un "parche" temporal.

Para generar el fichero en excel utilizó:

```
$reportes = Bitacora::ReportesExcel(); //método que devuelve el array de datos
foreach ($reportes as $key => $value) {
    $writer->addRow( WriterEntityFactory::createRowFromArray($value, $styleBody));
}
```

¿Alguna recomendación a modificar en el código?

Comment: Llenar el arreglo dentro de un ciclo termina siendo lo mismo que obtener todas las filas con `->fetchAll(). Definitivamente, no debes cargar todo en un arreglo. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código con el que exportas Excel.

Comment: ¿En qué contexto ocurre el error, en la obtención de los registros de BD o en la escritura del Excel? Convendría revisar varias cosas, como que la BD esté optimizada (esto lo puedes revisar ejecutando la misma consulta con `EXPLAIN` en el SGBD y comprobando la información). Así sabrás si debes optimizar a nivel de BD o a nivel de código (tanto los fetch como la escritura del archivo). La doc de PDO recomienda que no se use `fetchAll` cuando se esperan grandes resultados. El problema no es tanto que se cree o no un gran array, sino que fetchAll lo crea de golpe y eso puede desbordar la memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencioné en comentarios, no debes crear un arreglo con esa cantidad de datos. La primera opción es devolver el resultado de ejecutar la consulta y crear el ciclo leyendo cada fila:

```
$result = Bitacora::ReportesExcel(); // Resultado de consulta, no un arreglo
while($fila = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $writer->addRow( WriterEntityFactory::createRowFromArray($fila, $styleBody));
}
```

Esto ayudará a prevenir que el arreglo consuma la memoria disponible, sin embargo, si estás usando *PHPSpreadSheet*, este tampoco es muy amigable al manejar grandes cantidades de datos y sugiere algunas acciones para [ahorrar memoria](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/memory_saving/#memory-saving), que también puede ocasionar otros problemas, especialmente en tiempo de ejecución.

### Alternativa

Te sugiero echarle un vistazo a [Box / Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) que en su descripción menciona:

> Spout is a PHP library to read and write spreadsheet files (CSV, XLSX and ODS), in a fast and scalable way. Contrary to other file readers or writers, it is capable of processing very large files while keeping the memory usage really low (less than 3MB).

En resumen: Contrario a otros lectores o generadores de hojas de cálculo, es capaz de procesar archivos muy grandes mientras mantiene el uso de memoria realmente bajo (menos de 3mb).

Solo faltaría comprobar si el soporte para [estilos](https://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/#styling) cumple con tus necesidades.